# Firebase Auth state check in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

Currently I need to set up a check whether a user is logged in or not to then act accordingly (open home or log in screen). I'm using only email authentication.

**How to check user firebase auth state in flutter?**

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353730/firebase-login-with-flutter-using-onauthstatechanged?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I failed to check auth state in this way:

```
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        home: (_checkLogin() == true ? new PostAuthScaffold() : new PreAuthScaffold())
    );
  }
}

bool _checkLogin() {
  return !(auth.currentUser == null);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also check your auth status inside `initState` like so:

```
class CheckAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckAuthState createState() => new _CheckAuthState();
}

class _CheckAuthState extends State<CheckAuth> {
  bool isLoggedIn;
  @override
  void initState() {
    isLoggedIn = false;
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) => user != null
        ? setState(() {
            isLoggedIn = true;
          })
        : null);
    super.initState();
    // new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoggedIn ? new Home() : new LoginScreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: returns "Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null" error. Should I try to manually change isLoggedIn value every time user logs in or out and store the value in Shared Preferences?

Comment: That is because I forgot to initialize the value, I have update the code

Answer (score 5):

What about

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
  setState(() => isAuthenticated = user != null);
})
```

Comment: tried this method and also just in case with "user.email != null", but it doesn't seem to work - it still keeps returning to log in page after the app is reopened. Thank you

Comment: "still keeps returning to log in page after the app is reopened." why do you think this is related to the code I posted?

Comment: I used isAuthenticated variable to open appropriate page: 
      home: _isAuthenticated == true ? new HomeScreen() : new LogInScreen(). Is that a wrong way of doing it?

Comment: Difficult to say from that code snippet. It might be right, but you should test above code if it returns the expected result.

Comment: yeah I can successfuly sign up and log in (thanks to your answer to my previous question), but if I close my app after I log in and then open it again - the log in screen pops up again (instead of home screen as expected)

Comment: Is the code in my answer executed when the login page shows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168920/discussion-between-darkhan-and-gunter-zochbauer).