# Flutter Firebase signout

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am trying to return the user to the login page once they sign out from the app but goodness,nothing is working. I am getting exceptions like `Bad state: Future already completed` or the app returns to the login screen but the previous screen still exists in the stack when I hit back.

Here is my code:

```
_logOut() async{
    await _auth.signOut().then((value){
      print("***** log out");
      //Navigator.pop(context);
      //Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>new MyApp()));
    });
   // Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
  }
```

Comment: You should use Navigator.push and Navigator.pop for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out every function from `Navigator`, this worked finally:

```
_logOut() async{
    await _auth.signOut().then((_){
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/login", ModalRoute.withName("/home"));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not manually send user to login page after they sign out. Instead you should listen to the user's authentication state change and choose the page that you should show to your user based on their authentication state.

Checkout my answer here for more details:
[Firebase Login with Flutter using onAuthStateChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353730/firebase-login-with-flutter-using-onauthstatechanged/50632612#50632612)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, routeName)
```