# dart future method with bool return type always returns false

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling class method which is in a different file from the main method of main.dart. Here I am trying to get the session status of the user. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the return value always returns false when called in from the main method, but returns true if printed out in the actual method.

Here the expected result is true as the user is currently in the system and is signed in.

Here is my main method -

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  await Authenticate().getSessionStatus().then((status) => {
    print(status)
  });
}
```

Here is my class method -

```
class Authenticate {
  Future<bool> getSessionStatus() async {
    bool _isSessionActive = false;
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        //print('User is currently signed out!');
        _isSessionActive = false;
      } else {
        //print('User is signed in!');
        _isSessionActive = true;
      }
    });
    return _isSessionActive;
  }
}
```

The print statements inside the Authenticate class method, if turned on returns true which is the expected value, but calling the getSessionStatus method from the main method and then printing the value of the status variable always returns false. I believe it has something to do with order in which it is processed, but I am not able to fix it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check if the user is logged with `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`, since this method only notifies when the user status changes.

You can use the [`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html) instead:

```dart
class Authenticate {
  Future<bool> getSessionStatus() async {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance?.currentUser != null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello enzo, I get a red line under the .then.

Comment: What does the red line say?

Comment: The method 'then' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Comment: I've updated my solution, see if it works now.

Comment: This is what I get now - Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'FirebaseAuth' which excludes null.
 - 'FirebaseAuth' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('../../../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-1.4.1/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance?.currentUser != null;

Comment: This is just a warning, but you can get rid of it by replacing `instance?.currentUser` with `instance.currentUser`.

Comment: Thanks enzo, just for clarity, what does the question mark do in dart? Also when am I supposed to use the authStateChanges method. Could you explain it with a small scenario?

Comment: The `authStateChanges` is commonly used with a `StreamBuilder` widget and you can use it if you want to keep track of your user log-state and pick the right widget for it. I didn't know your use case so I suggested using `currentUser`, but it's recommended refactoring your code to use `authStateChanges` instead. You can take look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45353730/9997212) to see how you can implement it. About the question mark, it's related to null-safety, you can take a look at [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#smarter-null-aware-methods).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot await the `StreamSubscription` (which the compiler should warn you about) returned by `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen(...)`. Below is a minimal example to illustrate what is happening.

```
void main() async {
  bool test = await awaitMe();
  print('Main received:' + test.toString());
}

Future<bool> awaitMe() async {
  bool innerVal = false;
  print('start');
  await streamMe().listen((val) {
    print('Listener received: ' + val.toString());
    innerVal = true;
  });
  print('end');
  return innerVal;
}

Stream<bool> streamMe () async* {
  yield true;
}
```

This will print:

```
start
end
Main received:false
Listener received: true
```

So you are actually not awaiting anything.

Comment: Hello puelo, this makes sense, in that case should be making the navigation right from the authenticate class method? or as enzo has mentioned should I be using the currentUser property to check if the user is signed in or not?

Comment: If you are only interested in the current status at the exact time of invoking the method, the answer by enzo is probably better suited. As he said: `authStateChanges` is a listener which you can use to be notified about any changes in the auth state (e.g. logging out a user from your app if necessary)

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, when the user opens up the app if the user was already signed in, navigate the user to the products page if not to the sign in page.

Comment: Then i think enzos method is probably more straightforward.