# On this synchronous function second statement is running before 1st statement

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, firebase-authentication

```
String ok ="/login";
  String _loggedInFunction(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
         ok = "/login";

      }else{ ok = "/home";}

      print(ok);


      print(user);

    });
    print("Reading 1st");
    return ok;
  }
```

I can't be able to understand whether the FirebaseAuth.instance.... is an asynchronous function. Because second statement is running before the first one, but how can I apply "await" keyword here, While applying "await" keyword before FirebaseAuth.instance... .it's showing it is not a Future event.

And also I can you explain me why I can't be able return "ok" variable which is inside if statement directly, it's showing me an error.

I used this code to skip the login if the user restart the app. Do you have any recommended code for this purpose??

Output of the above code

```
I/flutter ( 6405): Reading 1st
I/flutter ( 6405): /home
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353730/firebase-login-with-flutter-using-onauthstatechanged) might be helpful to understand what onAuthStateChanged does

Answer (score 2):

The `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen` is not a promise but a listener. That means you can't await it or use `then` to wait on it. It will trigger each time the auth state changes. You are just listening to those changes.