# How to differentiate between regular users and anonymous users

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app is available for use with or without an account (as a guest).
When the app launches, I want to determine whether the user is a regular user or an anonymous user; if the user is a regular user, I want to determine whether the user is signed in or signed out; if signed in, show the homepage; otherwise, show the login page.
If the user is an anonymous user, then directly show HomePage.

If the user has not created an account anonymously, then allow them to create one.

When I use `signInAnonymously()` it's creating a new anonymous account each time.

Summary

show loginpage => if the user has not created an account both ways || regular user is not signin.

show Homepage => regular user is sigin || anonymous account is created.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine whether a user is anonymous by checking the [`isAnonymous` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/isAnonymous.html) of their profile.

I typically also add a check on whether the user has any [`providerData`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/providerData.html), as the `isAnonymous` flag may show as `false` when the user has linked-then-unlinked a provider.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to call signInAnonymously on every launch.  You're supposed to use an auth state observer **first** to find out if a user is signed in (anonymous or not), then using the result of that (now knowing if there is any user signed in or not), decide how to proceed.  If you find there is a user already signed in, you can then check the User object property `isAnonymous` to see if they are anonymous or not.

See:

- [Firebase Login with Flutter using onAuthStateChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353730/firebase-login-with-flutter-using-onauthstatechanged)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#authstatechanges

Comment: so, I can perform `isAnonymous`  only if the user signed in(has.data) ,if the user signed out,how to perform `isAnonymous`?

Comment: If the user is signed out, you don't know anything about them at all.  They're signed out.  Have to sign in before you have any access to the user data. That's why you have to wait for the auth state observer to tell you what's know, at the time it's known.

Comment: So, is it not possible to check whether an anonymous account was created or not at a direct check?

Comment: I'm a bit confusing. The auth state observer tells that user account was created or not, or signed in or signout status?.

Comment: It indicates sign in or sign out.  You have to decide after than what to do. If the user is signed out, you need to figure out what you want to do to sign them in.

Comment: so,my question. Is there any way to check if an account has been created or not?

Comment: No, not on the frontend. The only thing you can know using the client SDK is if the user was able to sign in using the SDK's API. If you wanted to know something outside of that, you would have to write a backend with the firebase admin sdk to implement something special yourself.

Comment: As per your answer,is the auth state observer checking both regular account and anonymous account status or only regular account status ?

Comment: It tells you when **any** user account is signed in.  It doesn't care what kind it is. They are all just user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the sign in with email in firebase so that your user can login in both ways. In your system , maybe you could do some checking when user launch the app for example you can check if their email exists by calling firebase authentication.